# Which orbital class rocket has highest TWR at liftoff?

Tags: rockets, engines, thrust

Which orbital class rocket (active or retired) has the highest thrust to weight ratio at liftoff?

Comment: I thought this had been asked before, but if has, I could not find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like JAXA's [SS-520](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-Series_(rocket_family)) with launch mass of 2,600 kg and 14,600 kgF average thrust would have TWR of about 5.6

data found [here](https://spaceflight101.com/ss-520-5-launch-preview/)

Comment: Video of launch here - https://youtu.be/OeW-Qqu9-8U?t=28 6 G acceleration?

Comment: The only SS-520 that successfully completed an orbital mission was fitted with a 78kg third stage. Additionally, [the original paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/0094-5765(82)90107-2) reports a 14.2 ton average vacuum thrust, using some ideal rocket theory and the papers data the sea level thrust would be about 12.7 ton rounded up, i.e. 12.7/2.678 = 4.74 TWR  (admittedly the paper is from 1982 and the orbital flight using the SS-520 was in 2018, so not entirely unlikely they improved the thrust)

Comment: To be fair, I cannot find any specification for the Mu-3H thrust data so it might as well be vacuum thrust too. Consequently assuming a similar correction for the Mu-3H thrust, the SS-520 used for the TRICOM-1R launch would still have the highest TWR

Comment: Ah, this is one of the Japanese ones which does its gravity turn at T-∞ :-D

Comment: @JörgWMittag Not really -∞, just T-(couple hours) when the erector is angled to the launch angle ;)

Answer (score 5):

I took the data from the JSR Launch Vehicle Database, available [here](https://planet4589.org/space/lvdb/lv.html). This includes take-off thrust and launch mass, so the Thrust-to-Weight Ratio was easily calculated. Unfortunately this list also includes many missiles and sounding rockets and I was too lazy too properly filter them with some other list of orbital class launch vehicles. However, eyeballing the list for orbital class launch vehicles with successful non-test missions, the [Mu-3H](http://www.astronautix.com/m/mu-3h.html) seems to be the highest. It has a TWR of about 4.9, which certainly is quite high. Most of the [Mu-family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(rocket_family)) rockets have very high TWR.

---

After some further digging on the Mu-family I found [a source](https://doi.org/10.2322/jjsass1969.28.359) in Japanese with sea-level thrusts and [another](https://doi.org/10.2514/6.IAC-04-IAA.6.15.3.06) (in English) with take-off mass for each configuration of the Mu-family rockets, which gives the following TWRs:

1. 4.74 - M-3C
2. 4.57 - M-3S/M-3H
3. 4.52 - M-4S

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the question refers to thrust to "total vehicle" weight ratio, I would opine that the ratio is determined by the mission.  A heavy launch-to-orbit vehicle would be loaded to get the heaviest load to space and have a low thrust to weight ratio. An anti-missile missle would have a high thrust to weight ratio to accelerate rapidly and get to an approaching missile as far away from it's target as possible.  I don't see any value in this parameter as a figure of merit.

Comment: Using a high thrust to "total vehicle" weight ratio would result in a very rapid acceleration of the rocket and thus would require a stronger and heavier rocket structure. Also the payload structure should resist the rapid acceleration and would be heavier.

Comment: Somebody asks: "Which animal runs the fastest?" You telling them: "I don't see any value in speed as a parameter for classifying animals" is not a useful answer